# difference between moment js functions and javascript date functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Actually i am thinking about to use `moment.js` in my new project.because my new project is a employee working sheet application.

I read the `moment.js` documents.

We can get the current date by using the below code in moment.js

```
moment().valueOf();
```

We can get the current date by using javascript

```
new Date()
```

> The both are giving same result. with same speed (so no performance issue )
>
> also `formatting`, `get` methods and `set` methods are already has `javascript`. then why i go to moment.js?

Please give me some explanations about the difference's. And let me know which one is best for my new project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Moment.js

A lightweight JavaScript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates.

**Reason why we use Moment.js** - Many web applications today, especially social ones, deal with the concept of time. They are usually employed to sort events or posts, or to mark the moment in which something happens. You can think of your Twitter timeline or your GitHub news feed. JavaScript has a Date object that you can use to manipulate dates, but it often doesn’t have all you need in your web applications

The `Moment.js` library not only parses dates from strings, but it may also be used to validate, manipulate, and format dates. It supports internationalization, which is so important with dates, as well as human-friendly formatting like "Last Friday at 9:48".

These are all good things for sure, but today's order of the day is date parsing, so let's get into how that works.

`Moment.js` creates a wrapper for the Date object rather than extend it. To reference the wrapper object, simply call the moment() getter function. The Moment prototype is exposed through the `moment.fn` property, so you can add your own functions to it if you are so inclined.

**Courtesy of**

[Managing Dates and Times Using Moment.js](http://www.netorials.com/tutorials/managing-dates-and-times-using-moment-js/)

[A Roundup of Popular JavaScript Date Parsing Libraries: Moment.js](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/a-roundup-of-popular-javascript-date-parsing-libraries-moment.js.html#fbid=3dW1Y3mIiyD)

Comment: If you just copy and paste, mark it as a quote: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/a-roundup-of-popular-javascript-date-parsing-libraries-moment.js.html#fbid=GNIGwOSZoi0 ;p

Answer (score 11):

`Moment.js` is convenient when you want to manipulate `Dates`.

An Example for moment is given below

```
moment()
  .add(7, 'days')
  .subtract(1, 'months')
  .year(2009)
  .hours(0)
  .minutes(0)
  .seconds(0);

moment().endOf('day').fromNow();
```

But if formatting, getting and setting is all you need, you might not need a library for that.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, I would suggest to go with `moment.js`. It is one of the most popular Date parsing library.

moment.js has a various inbuilt function's available which is easy to use.

It will save your development time.

Manipulating and parsing dates is very easy.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to what you're trying to do.

MomentJS provides an API that pretty-much wraps the native Date object, which is why you call `.valueOf`. `new Date` is simply giving you the native Date objects (and to manipulate it using moment, you'd need to pass it to its constructor).

I would say general rule of thumb:

- If you're creating a date for use on the site or as some kind of UI element, use Moment.
- If you're storing a date back to a service layer, use Date.
- If you're working in a method that's manipulating the date, use Moment; If that then needs to be passed to another service layer, call `.valueOf` and save it off.

Moment is great for the UX, but isn't a "standard" (and therefore wouldn't be ideal for serialization/storage).

Answer (score 0):

Moment.js has a good support for adding, subtracting, advanced formatting, finding differences between two days. Also it has internationalization support so you can convert to any language very easily.

Answer (score 0):

just like any library comes with a purpose to aid with something and make it easy to work. momemt.js makes working with dates PAINLESS.

working with dates considering the timezone and formats factors etc is very difficult, but moment.js makes it a breeze to work with dates.

read more [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/momentjs-simplifies-working-with-date-values-in-javascript/)